# openssl erro after machine restart decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

using openssl 0.9.8 in C++ application .

Things are working fine and suddenly following errors are encountered.
No change in code, certificate or in peer Application is done.

```
error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac:s3_pkt.c:426:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:288:
error:1408F096:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:encrypted length too long:s3_pkt.c:346:

M/C Details:Linux awtah.dispatchserver1 3.6.11-1.fc16.i686 #1 SMP Mon Dec 17 21:36:23 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

These error was random.
Even though application uses it’s own opnesssl 0.9.8 and M/C have 1.0.0j-fips.

```
-bash-4.2# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
built on: Tue May 15 18:44:01 UTC 2012
platform: linux-elf
options:  bn(64,32) md2(int) rc4(8x,mmx) des(ptr,risc1,16,long) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -Wa,--noexecstack -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  aesni dynamic
```

On reinstalling 1.0.0j-fips on this Machine error got fixed.

Now for the same application on Fedora 14, after reboot we have encountered the above problem.

```
Linux 3UPCAWT605 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686 #1 SMP Mon Oct 18 23:56:17 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Any pointer what is the root cause of this problem or how to fix this.
Open SSL installed on second M/C

```
built on: Wed Sep  7 18:59:14 UTC 2011
platform: linux-elf
options:  bn(64,32) md2(int) rc4(8x,mmx) des(ptr,risc1,16,long) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -Wa,--noexecstack -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  aesni dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

The cbc padding check seems to be failing.That can be triggered by some elements changing the data in the network,or the library was expecting something and got something else.For multi-threading environments callbacks of lock should be registered with openssl library.

For instance this is a library behavior ,in which you cant do much except re-creating ssl context and starting from the beginning on this error.

Some machines also support instruction sets for accelerating the library encryption/decryption,you may want to disable those instructions by exporting openssl environment variables.